# How to "scan to e-mail" documents without having the e-mail leave our LAN and automatically dump attachments to user folders?

Tags: windows-server-2003, email

We have some scan to e-mail multifunction machines that are networked. Our e-mail is hosted with Google Apps and our connection to the Internet is a plain old DSL line so our connection isn't very fast. We could probably have some internal mail server? I'm trying to figure out a solution where we can send e-mails to users without having it upload to Google because of our poor upload speeds. It would be even better if the e-mail option somehow dumped the email attachments to a designated folder under each users' my documents.

We have a Win 2003 server and the vast majority of our client computers are running Windows XP. Any ideas? We can probably fit in a Linux server if that helps with the solution but there is pretty much no room for solutions that require $.

Comment: Most such devices I've seen can also scan to PDF or JPEG. Doesn't yours have that capability?

Comment: It does scan documents as a TIFF or a PDF but users need to be able to retrieve the document off the machine somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only answer is to run some internal mail server.
Use a slightly amended domain perhaps...

so the user emails his scan to my.name@ihatemfdevices.yourdomain.com
which has an mx pointing at an internal server. If your linux/perl skills are good you coupd probably strip all attachments that come to the server and drop them into the relevant folders. Alternatively you could make sure the mfds see different DNS to everyone else?

Firewall off all but the mfds from your new "mail server" and you don't really need to bother coding for any other cases but the exact mail the mfd sends.

Pretty horrifying solution, but it might work.